# XPath with FilePath

Tags: xml, xpath, xpointer

Is there any standard (or practical) notation for expressing filepath and xpath together?

Such as...

```
xml.xml:///a/b/c
```

I believe I saw somewhere else but I can't find the page.

[UPDATE]

I think I'm asking about `XPointer`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `#` instead:

```
xlink:href="http://dog.com/dogbreeds.xml#xpointer(id('Rottweiler'))"
```

or, a shorter version:

```
xlink:href="http://dog.com/dogbreeds.xml#Rottweiler"
```